# Prove that $T:(C[2,3],||\cdot||_\infty)$ is absolute continuity

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

**NOTE C[a,b] are all the continuous functions in [2,3]**

$T:(C[2,3],||\cdot||_\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ with $T(f)=\int_2^3 f(t)dt + f(2)$

****Prove** that $Τ(f)$ is absolutely continuous**

Let $\epsilon > 0 $ and $d= $ ***(blank for now will come back to this later)***

Let $f,g \in C[2,3]$ with $||f-g||_\infty <d$

**Our goal here is to prove that** $|T(f)-T(g)|<d$

$|T(f)-T(g)|=| \int_2^3 f(t)dt + f(2) - \int_2^3 g(t)dt - f(2)|=|\int_2^3 f(t)- g(t)dt |\leq \int_2^3| f(t)dt - \int_2^3 g(t)|dt \leq $

$\leq||f-g||_\infty (3-2)<d=\epsilon$

**Question $1$**: I took $f(2)$ as a number was that corrrect? if not i would take $f(2) - g(2)$ making no sense i dont know where i could go with that.

**Question $2$**: I believe that my idea is correct but correct me if i have any mistakes.

Comment: Absolute continuity of $T$ doesn’t make sense as $T$ is not defined on a real interval.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net hey im sorry for the typo I meant to prove it for T.

Comment: That doesn’t make sense. See my previous comment.

Comment: There is one $f(2)$ too many...

Comment: @Pacciu isnt $T(g)= \int_2^3 g(t)dt + f(2)$ ?

Comment: By definition $T(g) = \int_2^3 g(t)\text{d} t + g(2)$, isn't it?

Comment: @Pacciu is it? thats what im asking in question 1.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net im talking about $T(f)$

Comment: It doesn’t make sense either as $T(f)$ is a real number, not a function.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net i define T as the metric space with all the functions from [2,3] with the sup norm. Thats what my proffesor gave me as an exercise so either he is dumb dumb which i dont believe is the case here either you do not understand what im asking either i failed to translate accordingly which should be the case but i dont see any mistakes.

Comment: Can you write down the definition of absolute continuity ? And do you agree that $T(f)$ is a real number and not a function ?

Comment: I understand what you are making point of i will go ahead and ask him in the next lesson we have there is no point trying to answer an exercise i have no idea of what im talking about, thanks for making this point so i can get more in depth with the metrics :)

Comment: In fact you’re not asking to prove that $T$ is absolutely continuous, but that it is Lipschitz continuous if I understand well what you wrote later in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126377/discussion-between-steve-and-mathcounterexamples-net).